# SQL: select non-archived and referenced entries among three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I got the following database layout. The table on the left - the "exhibit" is somehow the parent. The one in the middle - the "flyer" table describes some data about the exhibit and is therefore linked to it by ex_ID. Let's say it's like versioning. Only the latest "flyer" (the highest ID) is important. On the right side you got "text" parts that reference a row in the "flyer" table directly.

[image]

So here's the question. How can I retrieve in ONE statements all flyers a) with the highest ID to a non-archived exhibit and that are b) referenced by non-archived text-parts. For example, as shown in the picture, ID 1 and 4 of the flyer-table should not be returned.

For a SQL expert, this might be an easy question. But for all others, that's learning. So, please, no down-voting.

Answer (score 0):

This statement returns only flyers with the highest id by exhibition, that are referenced by a non archived exhibition and have either not archived parts or no referenced parts at all:

```
SELECT
    f.id fid,
    f.ex_id,
    e.id eid,
    e.archived earchived,
    p.id pid,
    p.archived parchived
FROM
    Flyer f
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        MAX(id) max_id
    FROM
        Flyer
    GROUP BY
        ex_id
    ) t
ON
    f.id = t.max_id
INNER JOIN
    Exhibition e
ON
    f.ex_id = e.id
AND
    e.archived = false
LEFT JOIN
    Part p
ON
    f.id = p.fl_id
AND
    p.archived = false
;
```

**Explanation**

- The INNER JOIN to the subselect will give us the highest id of the
  Flyer table by Exhibition id.
- We use then an INNER JOIN to Exhibiton to get the details of the exhibiton, only if these are not archived
- and a LEFT JOIN to the part table to get only those parts that are not archived or non existent.

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4210/20)**

Comment: You are right. The flyer ID 2 should not be returned. My mistake, sorry. Imagine there are not parts but still an exhibit and some versions of a flyer. Then your SELECt won't return anything, because your are doing an inner join on parts first. Right? But still, I would like to get flyer 3 in that case.

Comment: If there's no part for a flyer at all in part. That's a completly different query :-)

Comment: It is not a different query, because the underlying schema is still the same. And changing the inner joins to left joins will get flyer ID 1,2 and 3 instead of only 3, or? Somehow I'm thinking of a SELECT MAX statement for exhibit + flyer and a simple SELECT statement for flyer + parts of which then the flyer ID's are merged into a set.

Comment: Why would you then not get ID 1?

Comment: Because for an exhibition only the highest ID of a flyer (or latest version) is of interest.